# Java taking data from the wrong variable

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing a short assignment involving generics. One of the methods is designed to replace an object in the generic set. I've posted the code below. I've fixed most of what's wrong, but the problem that persists is that Java is using the data from newObject instead of theList.get(i). I put in output statements to test it, and whenever I asked it to print anything from theList, it instead gave me data from newObject. OldObject outputted information without a problem.

```
public boolean replaceObject(T oldObject, T newObject){
       if (theList.size()==0){
           System.out.println("The set is empty");
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++){
           if ((oldObject.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(theList.get(i).toString()))==0){
               theList.remove(i);
               theList.add(newObject);
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;//executes if nothing found
   }
```

EDIT: Thanks for all of the responses, but the problem I'm concerned with is not that the search is skipping over entries, but rather that instead of searching through theList, it is only looking at newObject. theList.get(i) is NOT returning data from theList, the program is reading newObject and I don't know why.

Comment: Why are you using `toString.compareToIgnoreCase`? You could use `oldObject.equals(theList.get(i))` instead. Also, can you post some code that shows exactly the problem you are seeing, including the output statements that are giving you the wrong data and the code that populates `theList` and calls `replaceObject`?

Comment: Just wanted to say that I love the confidence in assuming that the problem is with Java, and no one until now noticed this tendency to use data from "wrong" variables.

Comment: "I put in output statements to test it, and whenever I asked it to print anything from theList, it instead gave me data from newObject." I don't see any output statements anywhere. It is impossible to tell what you are trying to output, and what you're seeing. Post a complete program, including what is stored in the list, and what oldObject and newObject are, along with what it outputs, and what you expect it to output.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want a replace operation: `theList.set(i, newObject);`.

EDIT: it's logic error: call remove() and add() in same loop.

Suppose the list=['a', 'b', 'c']:

In loop:

When i=0, list[0] is removed and 'd' is added, the list will be ['b', 'c', 'd'].

When i=1, 'b' is skipped!

Comment: The rest of the program operates fine, and I know I could be using better coding for replacing the object. The problem is that Java isn't taking any of the data from theList; whenever I call theList.get(i), it give me whatever is stored in newObject.

For example, I have an object named "object" stored in the list, and want to replace it with one named "example". When the program searches through the list, it isn't looking at the list for an object named "object", its looking only at the new object, "example".

Comment: @Paul: make sure you are passing `replaceObject(oldObject,newObject)`. oldObject be the first argument

Comment: Calling remove and add in the same loop can't be the solution. The method returns true after the object is found; therefore, it won't skip over the next value because the program has already found the relevant data. The problem I'm having is that the program isn't searching the list at all, and is instead looking solely at newObject.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an item from a list, all items below it come one step above to occupy a newer position.

for example - assume theList as follows:

```
index 0 --> a
index 1 --> b
index 2 --> c

for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) { }
```

// int i will be initially 0.

remove index 0 (removes a, but keeps the index, then b and c will move up )

after remove 0 ( because i == 0 )

```
index 0 --> b
index 1 --> c
```

add new item d (this will occupy the last index which is 2)

```
index 0 --> b
index 1 --> c
index 2 --> d //this is new.
```

now increment i ( i++ ) therefore i will be equal to 1, 
then remove index 1 (because i is 1)

the list becomes

```
index 0 --> b
index 1 --> d
// notice that c is removed because that was at index 1. now d takes index 1
```

add new element e

```
index 0 --> b
index 1 --> d
index 2 --> e
```

and so on.

so every time you remove and add, you are not getting the right value,  simply because ArrayList rearranges the index of the items.

Using "set", may not work, as it is used for replacing existing elements. It cannot be used to for adding new elements.

Option 1)
A better option would be to use HashMaps. This would make sure you are removing the correct element. 
You will also be able to add new elements to the HashMap, with the appropriate key values.

Option 2)
Instead of removing an element, set it as an empty String/Object. using "set". This way you are never changing the index.

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing to/from a list while iterating is playing with shap knifes:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++){
       if  ...
           theList.remove(i);
           theList.add(newObject);
```

The iterator gets out of sync.

Instead, you could use intermediate lists to store Objects to remove and add, and add and remove them in a final step:
Sample, only removing:

```
public void remove (String name) 
{
    List <Person> blacklist = new ArrayList <Person> ();
    for (Person p : people) 
    {
        if (p.getName ().equals (name))
        {
            blacklist.add (p);
        }
    }
    people.removeAll (blacklist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine for me. See to it that you are setting the list correctly.

Here is the simple sample code.

```
public class Test<T> {
public List<T> theList;

public Test()
{
    this.theList = new ArrayList<T>();
}

public boolean replaceObject(T oldObject, T newObject)
{
    if (theList.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("The set is empty");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < theList.size(); i++) {
        if ((oldObject.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(theList.get(i).toString())) == 0) {
            theList.remove(i);
            theList.add(newObject);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;//executes if nothing found
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Test<String> t = new Test<String>();
    t.theList.add("ABC");
    t.theList.add("DEF");
    t.theList.add("GHI");
    System.out.println(t.replaceObject("DEF", "PQR"));
    System.out.println(t.theList.toString());

}}
```

The output comes as expected:
true
[ABC, GHI, PQR]